# Indexeddb get all records different from certain value

Tags: node.js, npm, nosql, indexeddb

Is there a build in way to get all the records which are different from certain value in indexed-db.

In SQL this is something like

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 <> 'somedata';`

I see a there is a build in method [IDBKeyRange.only()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBKeyRange/only),
but I do not see method which return diffrence. (Or maybe I do not see simple way)

Yes, I know if we iterate through the records we can do this. I speak about quick build in way to perform this.

Unfortunately the method

`IDBKeyRange.bound(value, value, true, true)`

return error, but this is exactly  what is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDBKeyRange.bound(value, value, true, true)` is an error because it's an impossible interval - there are no keys that are simultaneously both higher than value and lower than value.

But you can use *two* ranges:

`IDBKeyRange.upperBound(value, true)` gives you all the records from the start of the store/index to value (but not including value).
`IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(value, true)` gives you all the records from value (but not including value) to the end of the store/index.

If you know the number of records is relatively small, you can use these with the `getAll()` methods, otherwise iteration is the best approach.

(We've talked about adding more complex queries so you could do a "set of ranges" rather than having to query two ranges, but that hasn't manifested in any implementations yet.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. For me using two ranges is not a solution. The problem is that this should be used in relative big data set >= 10k. I have to use iteration and the speed is acceptable for me, since other search conditions are used in combination